# Duplication values in autoincremented field on replication

Tags: mysql, triggers, auto-increment, database-replication

That's a strange issue.

There are source MySQL DB (MASTER) and its replic (SLAVE). It's a (as you understand its a MASTER-SLAVE) statement-bases replication, because I need triggers to run on the SLAVE side.

1. The original triggers were replaced by new ones.
2. Every table has 3 trigers: on INSERT, on UPDATE and on DELETE.
3. Trigers were generated by a single pattern and differ only by params.
4. Every trigger does a single INSERT query to a table (CHANGES) on the SLAVE.
5. This table is not replicated and exists only on the SLAVE.
6. There is an autoincremented column (ID - bigint) in this table.
7. None of the triggers set or modify values of the column ID. The DB sets a default values for it.
8. It's about 20 inserts executed on CHANGES per minute.
9. I see errors with duplicated values.

How it's possible?

Let's again:

1. An INSERT / UPDATE / DELETE query is executed on MASTER.
2. This change is replicated to SLAVE.
3. A trigger is called and inserts a row to the CHANGES.
4. Duplicated values error is generated.

And as I said before, none of the triggers set or modify value of the autoincremented field (ID). And only triggers work with table CHANGES.

I understand that two or more triggers can be called together, and try to do INSERT together, but I think DB should easy solve this. Or that's a very bad DB.

**UPD:**

```
CREATE TABLE `CHANGES` (
`id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`field1` ENUM(...) NOT NULL,
`field2` BOOL NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
`field3` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
`field4` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`field5` TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TRIGGER `tr_TABLE_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `TABLE`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `CHANGES` (`field1`, `field3`, `field4`, `field5`)
    VALUES ("value1", "value3", "value4", "value5");
END
```

**UPD 2:**

I found a temporary and more dirty method - added BEFORE INSERT trigger for CHANGES to set ID manually.

It works. But I still can't figure out why the native AUTO_INCREMENT mechanism is generating duplicated ids.

Comment: Can you add the code & tables involved (shorted to relevant columns only)

Comment: There are multiple type of replication. What is your `binlog_format` value?

Comment: The Table and trigger sample I added to question. **binlog_format** is statement-based, because I need triggers to be executed on the SLAVE side.